# Can a ScrollView be bounded by maxHeight?

Tags: react-native, expo

The [ScrollView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html) doc mention:

> Keep in mind that ScrollViews must have a bounded height in order to work, since they contain unbounded-height children into a bounded container (via a scroll interaction). In order to bound the height of a ScrollView, either set the height of the view directly (discouraged) or make sure all parent views have bounded height. Forgetting to transfer {flex: 1} down the view stack can lead to errors here, which the element inspector makes easy to debug.

Is it possible to bound the ScrollView with maxHeight? So that ScrollView will expand, and start to scroll only if children is above maxHeight?

I'm trying to create a centered modal component with dynamic width/height, and that permits to scroll when needed. I've bounded the height to 95%. It looks like the scrollview always takes 95% of the screen. If I remove the scrollview it works as expected.

On the screenshot, I'd like the red box to be centered, and the white box should not be present. Here is an [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/Bk3EOXQwG) if you want to try solving my problem.

[image]

Can someone find a solution? or can someone confirm it is not possible and why? Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Someone just helped me solve this. I need to add `flexGrow: 0` on the ScrollView.

This is because ScrollView has `flexGrow: 1` by default. Note that using `flex: 0` on ScrollView won't work as it does not override the default flexGrow.

https://snack.expo.io/S1N027QPf